# Xamarin iOS INVoiceShortcutCenter crash

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

in my app I have the following line of code:

```
var allShortcuts = await INVoiceShortcutCenter.SharedCenter.GetAllVoiceShortcutsAsync();
```

When this line gets called, the app crashes and the following Error appears:

```
Error Domain=IntentsErrorDomain Code=7001 "Failed to get voice shortcuts" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to get voice shortcuts, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001a82460 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application."}}
```

Has someone and idea why this happens?

Comment: For siri-shortcut you could check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/introduction-to-ios12/siri-shortcuts .

Comment: I looked at this before, but I don't find an answer for my problem.

Comment: It would be better to share your sample so that I can test it on my side .